# Moduli spaces of 'generalized mutually unbiased bases'

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, it.information-theory, quantum-mechanics

Mutually unbiased bases in $\mathbb{C}^n$ with a chosen inner product are collections of orthonormal bases such that for each pair of orthonormal bases $e_i,f_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$ we have $|\langle e_i, f_j\rangle|^2=\frac{1}{n}$ for all $i,j$. Computing the maximal size of such a family for a fixed $n$ is a well-known problem.

This problem can be rephrased more algebraically: we can construct rank 1 projectors
$$p_i=e_i\otimes\langle-,e_i\rangle,\ q_j=f_j\otimes\langle-,f_j\rangle,$$ and accordingly study collections of rank 1 projectors such that $$p_i p_j=0=p_j p_i, q_i q_j=0=q_j q_i, \text{Tr} (p_iq_j)=\frac{1}{n}.$$

[Bondal and Zhdanovskiy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.15388.pdf) generalize this problem to studying $r$-unbiased projectors by instead considering a non-oriented graph $\Gamma$ with a weight $r_{ij}$ assigned to each edge $i\to j$, assigning a projector $p_i$ to each vertex $i$  and studying families of projectors $p_i$ such that $p_i$ and $p_j$ are orthogonal if there is no edge $i\to j$ and $\text{Tr} (p_ip_j)=r_{ij}$ otherwise. Then there are $d$ mutually unbiased bases if and only if there is such a configuration of projectors for $\Gamma$ a complete $d$-partite graph with $n$ vertices in each independent set and all weights set to $\frac{1}{n}.$

I am trying to apply algebraic geometry to construct some sort of moduli space for such configurations for arbitrary $\Gamma$ and not necessarily nonzero $r_{ij}$, but don't want to reinvent the wheel if someone has already done just that. And people have already approached mutually unbiased bases from a lot of different directions, so it's quite possible that this problem is well known in some area of math that I am woefully ignorant of. So, perhaps any of you know whether this generalization or anything similar to $r$-unbiased projectors appears under a different name somewhere?